# Can we send an automated notification to customer Who sends an email on closed case which is more than 30 day

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, process-builder, visual-flows

A case is closed and closed more than 30 days ( created a field to calculate - Today - case closed date ) and If Customer sends an email (Email message - incoming true) then send auto notification to customer. I tried created workflow and process builder but this is not working as expected. Can some one help me with a best solution.

If using apex trigger or flows or process builder , any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean to ask how to notify the customer if they send an email in response to a case that has been closed more than 30 days? Where will the customer be sending this email? Email 2 Case?

Comment: Yes, Customer sends / replies to Email to case

Comment: You need a trigger here, then.